# Bluetooth HC-05 module returns encoded data

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I have searched online, and haven't found anyone hitting this issue. Strangely my Bluetooth HC-05 is returning encoded data. I have tried using different boards - Induing, Uno, Freeduino and I have the same problem with them all.

The Bluetooth module I am using is a [HC-05 Bluetooth Module](https://www.fabtolab.com/radio/bluetooth/HC-05-bluetooth-module-6-pin).

When I pass 'AT' command, I expect the return to be 'OK'. I get data as

```
CF  A7  86  85
```

This is 8-bit data, and if I drop the MSB I would be:

```
4F  27  06  05
```

Instead I should have received:

```
4F  4B  0D  0A
```

I looked at the binary pattern to understand if this is something like 7 bit encoding used in GSM.

```
Actual Data
CF       A7       86       85
11001111 10100111 10000110 10000101

Expected Data
4F  4B  0D  0A
01001111 01001011 00001101 00001010
```

I have tried other AT commands and everything appears to be encoded.

The code I have written is pretty standard, module is blinking at 2 sec pulse (in command mode). I get encoded output for all AT commands. I even tried ORGL, INIT and other commands as suggested on various discussion threads.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BtDongle = SoftwareSerial(10, 11);

void setup() {
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(100);  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.write("AT Command: \n\n");
  BtDongle.begin(38400); 
}

void loop() {
  while(BtDongle.available()) {
    unsigned char data = BtDongle.read();
    Serial.println(data, HEX);
  }

  while(Serial.available()) {
    char data = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(data);
    BtDongle.print(data);
  }    
}
```

Comment: It looks like a configuration problem of the serial interface: try to play withe number of stop bits and the parity; there's probably one combination that will work.

Comment: I tried various combinations with Putty instead of the Arduino IDE's built in Serial Monitor. Here the output won't stop!  
  
    CFA78685CFA78685CFA78685CFA78685CFA78685CFA78685CFA78685...
  
  
In the built-in Serial Monitor  
HEX:
    AT
    CFA78685  
  
    AT+NAME?
    ABA6A0A629275469D62482C6C1B5416D5A60B18585CFA78685  
  
    AT+Version?
    C5AAA9A7A94D4A4C4A23E1
    
CHAR:
    AT  
    Ï§†…
    
    AT+NAME?  
    «¦ ¦Q'UiÖ$‚ÆÁµÁmZ`±……Ï§†…  
    
    AT+VERSION?
    «ª¢©*ÕÊ¦’ºÁµIab`°š˜˜CáÏ§†…

Comment: Well I faced a similar kind of problem with Wi-Fi module RN 171. Following are some tips that I would like you to check for.

Comment: Please share tips that I can check for?

Comment: It seems some bits are getting lost. Please add a buffer to both input and output and only start to transmit back to PC when you have received everything from BT.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same problem, and after a few researches, I found that it was related with a [bug](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2019) inside the library SoftwareSerial. Here is how to fix it :

- Download the two files of the [new version of the library](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src) on github
- Rename them into `mySoftwareSerial.cpp` and `mySoftwareSerial.h` and put them in the working folder
- Replace in the working file **and in the file `mySoftwareSerial.h`** the line `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>` into

  `#include "mySoftwareSerial.h"`
- Compile and send it to the arduino. It should work ! (Tested in AT mode at a baud rate of 38400, and in classical mode (+AT mode) with a baud rate of 57600 on a arduino nano)

You can find the file I used at the and of the post.

By the way, I also mention another problem I got which is not related but could help : in some models of HC-05 you have a pin `EN` instead of `KEY`. Here, instead of connecting the VCC to the `KEY` pin, you need to press the button on the top of the HC-05 board before starting the HC-05 module : this button will connect VCC to the pin 34 for you. But note that if you don't keep this button down, **you will be able to do only a subset of the commands** (for example, `AT+NAME?` won't work, while `AT+NAME=...` and `AT` will). You can find lot's of additional information [here](http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-with-hc-05-bluetooth-module-at-mode/).

### The files I used

This file is the "project file" used to forward the classical serial connection (Ctrl+Shift+M on arduino software) to the bluetooth device. Type `AT` commands here.

```
#include "mySoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial BTserial(7, 8); // RX | TX
// Connect the HC-05 TX to Arduino pin 2 RX. 
// Connect the HC-05 RX to Arduino pin 3 TX through a voltage divider.
// 

char c = ' ';

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Arduino is ready");
    Serial.println("Remember to select Both NL & CR in the serial monitor");

    // HC-05 default serial speed for AT mode is 38400
    BTserial.begin(38400);
}

void loop()
{

    // Keep reading from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
    if (BTserial.available())
    {  
        c = BTserial.read();
        Serial.write(c);
    }

    // Keep reading from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-05
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        c =  Serial.read();
        BTserial.write(c);  
    }

}
```

The file `mySoftwareSerial.h`, taken from the github page :

```
/*
SoftwareSerial.h (formerly NewSoftSerial.h) - 
Multi-instance software serial library for Arduino/Wiring
-- Interrupt-driven receive and other improvements by ladyada
   (http://ladyada.net)
-- Tuning, circular buffer, derivation from class Print/Stream,
   multi-instance support, porting to 8MHz processors,
   various optimizations, PROGMEM delay tables, inverse logic and 
   direct port writing by Mikal Hart (http://www.arduiniana.org)
-- Pin change interrupt macros by Paul Stoffregen (http://www.pjrc.com)
-- 20MHz processor support by Garrett Mace (http://www.macetech.com)
-- ATmega1280/2560 support by Brett Hagman (http://www.roguerobotics.com/)
This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
Lesser General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
The latest version of this library can always be found at
http://arduiniana.org.
*/

#ifndef SoftwareSerial_h
#define SoftwareSerial_h

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <Stream.h>

/******************************************************************************
* Definitions
******************************************************************************/

#ifndef _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF
#define _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF 64 // RX buffer size
#endif

#ifndef GCC_VERSION
#define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#endif

class SoftwareSerial : public Stream
{
private:
  // per object data
  uint8_t _receivePin;
  uint8_t _receiveBitMask;
  volatile uint8_t *_receivePortRegister;
  uint8_t _transmitBitMask;
  volatile uint8_t *_transmitPortRegister;
  volatile uint8_t *_pcint_maskreg;
  uint8_t _pcint_maskvalue;

  // Expressed as 4-cycle delays (must never be 0!)
  uint16_t _rx_delay_centering;
  uint16_t _rx_delay_intrabit;
  uint16_t _rx_delay_stopbit;
  uint16_t _tx_delay;

  uint16_t _buffer_overflow:1;
  uint16_t _inverse_logic:1;

  // static data
  static uint8_t _receive_buffer[_SS_MAX_RX_BUFF]; 
  static volatile uint8_t _receive_buffer_tail;
  static volatile uint8_t _receive_buffer_head;
  static SoftwareSerial *active_object;

  // private methods
  inline void recv() __attribute__((__always_inline__));
  uint8_t rx_pin_read();
  void setTX(uint8_t transmitPin);
  void setRX(uint8_t receivePin);
  inline void setRxIntMsk(bool enable) __attribute__((__always_inline__));

  // Return num - sub, or 1 if the result would be < 1
  static uint16_t subtract_cap(uint16_t num, uint16_t sub);

  // private static method for timing
  static inline void tunedDelay(uint16_t delay);

public:
  // public methods
  SoftwareSerial(uint8_t receivePin, uint8_t transmitPin, bool inverse_logic = false);
  ~SoftwareSerial();
  void begin(long speed);
  bool listen();
  void end();
  bool isListening() { return this == active_object; }
  bool stopListening();
  bool overflow() { bool ret = _buffer_overflow; if (ret) _buffer_overflow = false; return ret; }
  int peek();

  virtual size_t write(uint8_t byte);
  virtual int read();
  virtual int available();
  virtual void flush();
  operator bool() { return true; }

  using Print::write;

  // public only for easy access by interrupt handlers
  static inline void handle_interrupt() __attribute__((__always_inline__));
};

// Arduino 0012 workaround
#undef int
#undef char
#undef long
#undef byte
#undef float
#undef abs
#undef round

#endif
```

The file `mySoftwareSerial.cpp`, also taken from the github page:

```
/*
SoftwareSerial.cpp (formerly NewSoftSerial.cpp) - 
Multi-instance software serial library for Arduino/Wiring
-- Interrupt-driven receive and other improvements by ladyada
   (http://ladyada.net)
-- Tuning, circular buffer, derivation from class Print/Stream,
   multi-instance support, porting to 8MHz processors,
   various optimizations, PROGMEM delay tables, inverse logic and 
   direct port writing by Mikal Hart (http://www.arduiniana.org)
-- Pin change interrupt macros by Paul Stoffregen (http://www.pjrc.com)
-- 20MHz processor support by Garrett Mace (http://www.macetech.com)
-- ATmega1280/2560 support by Brett Hagman (http://www.roguerobotics.com/)
This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
Lesser General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
The latest version of this library can always be found at
http://arduiniana.org.
*/

// When set, _DEBUG co-opts pins 11 and 13 for debugging with an
// oscilloscope or logic analyzer.  Beware: it also slightly modifies
// the bit times, so don't rely on it too much at high baud rates
#define _DEBUG 0
#define _DEBUG_PIN1 11
#define _DEBUG_PIN2 13
// 
// Includes
// 
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "mySoftwareSerial.h"
#include <util/delay_basic.h>

//
// Statics
//
SoftwareSerial *SoftwareSerial::active_object = 0;
uint8_t SoftwareSerial::_receive_buffer[_SS_MAX_RX_BUFF]; 
volatile uint8_t SoftwareSerial::_receive_buffer_tail = 0;
volatile uint8_t SoftwareSerial::_receive_buffer_head = 0;

//
// Debugging
//
// This function generates a brief pulse
// for debugging or measuring on an oscilloscope.
#if _DEBUG
inline void DebugPulse(uint8_t pin, uint8_t count)
{
  volatile uint8_t *pport = portOutputRegister(digitalPinToPort(pin));

  uint8_t val = *pport;
  while (count--)
  {
    *pport = val | digitalPinToBitMask(pin);
    *pport = val;
  }
}
#else
inline void DebugPulse(uint8_t, uint8_t) {}
#endif

//
// Private methods
//

/* static */ 
inline void SoftwareSerial::tunedDelay(uint16_t delay) { 
  _delay_loop_2(delay);
}

// This function sets the current object as the "listening"
// one and returns true if it replaces another 
bool SoftwareSerial::listen()
{
  if (!_rx_delay_stopbit)
    return false;

  if (active_object != this)
  {
    if (active_object)
      active_object->stopListening();

    _buffer_overflow = false;
    _receive_buffer_head = _receive_buffer_tail = 0;
    active_object = this;

    setRxIntMsk(true);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

// Stop listening. Returns true if we were actually listening.
bool SoftwareSerial::stopListening()
{
  if (active_object == this)
  {
    setRxIntMsk(false);
    active_object = NULL;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

//
// The receive routine called by the interrupt handler
//
void SoftwareSerial::recv()
{

#if GCC_VERSION < 40302
// Work-around for avr-gcc 4.3.0 OSX version bug
// Preserve the registers that the compiler misses
// (courtesy of Arduino forum user *etracer*)
  asm volatile(
    "push r18 \n\t"
    "push r19 \n\t"
    "push r20 \n\t"
    "push r21 \n\t"
    "push r22 \n\t"
    "push r23 \n\t"
    "push r26 \n\t"
    "push r27 \n\t"
    ::);
#endif  

  uint8_t d = 0;

  // If RX line is high, then we don't see any start bit
  // so interrupt is probably not for us
  if (_inverse_logic ? rx_pin_read() : !rx_pin_read())
  {
    // Disable further interrupts during reception, this prevents
    // triggering another interrupt directly after we return, which can
    // cause problems at higher baudrates.
    setRxIntMsk(false);

    // Wait approximately 1/2 of a bit width to "center" the sample
    tunedDelay(_rx_delay_centering);
    DebugPulse(_DEBUG_PIN2, 1);

    // Read each of the 8 bits
    for (uint8_t i=8; i > 0; --i)
    {
      tunedDelay(_rx_delay_intrabit);
      d >>= 1;
      DebugPulse(_DEBUG_PIN2, 1);
      if (rx_pin_read())
        d |= 0x80;
    }

    if (_inverse_logic)
      d = ~d;

    // if buffer full, set the overflow flag and return
    uint8_t next = (_receive_buffer_tail + 1) % _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF;
    if (next != _receive_buffer_head)
    {
      // save new data in buffer: tail points to where byte goes
      _receive_buffer[_receive_buffer_tail] = d; // save new byte
      _receive_buffer_tail = next;
    } 
    else 
    {
      DebugPulse(_DEBUG_PIN1, 1);
      _buffer_overflow = true;
    }

    // skip the stop bit
    tunedDelay(_rx_delay_stopbit);
    DebugPulse(_DEBUG_PIN1, 1);

    // Re-enable interrupts when we're sure to be inside the stop bit
    setRxIntMsk(true);

  }

#if GCC_VERSION < 40302
// Work-around for avr-gcc 4.3.0 OSX version bug
// Restore the registers that the compiler misses
  asm volatile(
    "pop r27 \n\t"
    "pop r26 \n\t"
    "pop r23 \n\t"
    "pop r22 \n\t"
    "pop r21 \n\t"
    "pop r20 \n\t"
    "pop r19 \n\t"
    "pop r18 \n\t"
    ::);
#endif
}

uint8_t SoftwareSerial::rx_pin_read()
{
  return *_receivePortRegister & _receiveBitMask;
}

//
// Interrupt handling
//

/* static */
inline void SoftwareSerial::handle_interrupt()
{
  if (active_object)
  {
    active_object->recv();
  }
}

#if defined(PCINT0_vect)
ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
  SoftwareSerial::handle_interrupt();
}
#endif

#if defined(PCINT1_vect)
ISR(PCINT1_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(PCINT0_vect));
#endif

#if defined(PCINT2_vect)
ISR(PCINT2_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(PCINT0_vect));
#endif

#if defined(PCINT3_vect)
ISR(PCINT3_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(PCINT0_vect));
#endif

//
// Constructor
//
SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial(uint8_t receivePin, uint8_t transmitPin, bool inverse_logic /* = false */) : 
  _rx_delay_centering(0),
  _rx_delay_intrabit(0),
  _rx_delay_stopbit(0),
  _tx_delay(0),
  _buffer_overflow(false),
  _inverse_logic(inverse_logic)
{
  setTX(transmitPin);
  setRX(receivePin);
}

//
// Destructor
//
SoftwareSerial::~SoftwareSerial()
{
  end();
}

void SoftwareSerial::setTX(uint8_t tx)
{
  // First write, then set output. If we do this the other way around,
  // the pin would be output low for a short while before switching to
  // output high. Now, it is input with pullup for a short while, which
  // is fine. With inverse logic, either order is fine.
  digitalWrite(tx, _inverse_logic ? LOW : HIGH);
  pinMode(tx, OUTPUT);
  _transmitBitMask = digitalPinToBitMask(tx);
  uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(tx);
  _transmitPortRegister = portOutputRegister(port);
}

void SoftwareSerial::setRX(uint8_t rx)
{
  pinMode(rx, INPUT);
  if (!_inverse_logic)
    digitalWrite(rx, HIGH);  // pullup for normal logic!
  _receivePin = rx;
  _receiveBitMask = digitalPinToBitMask(rx);
  uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(rx);
  _receivePortRegister = portInputRegister(port);
}

uint16_t SoftwareSerial::subtract_cap(uint16_t num, uint16_t sub) {
  if (num > sub)
    return num - sub;
  else
    return 1;
}

//
// Public methods
//

void SoftwareSerial::begin(long speed)
{
  _rx_delay_centering = _rx_delay_intrabit = _rx_delay_stopbit = _tx_delay = 0;

  // Precalculate the various delays, in number of 4-cycle delays
  uint16_t bit_delay = (F_CPU / speed) / 4;

  // 12 (gcc 4.8.2) or 13 (gcc 4.3.2) cycles from start bit to first bit,
  // 15 (gcc 4.8.2) or 16 (gcc 4.3.2) cycles between bits,
  // 12 (gcc 4.8.2) or 14 (gcc 4.3.2) cycles from last bit to stop bit
  // These are all close enough to just use 15 cycles, since the inter-bit
  // timings are the most critical (deviations stack 8 times)
  _tx_delay = subtract_cap(bit_delay, 15 / 4);

  // Only setup rx when we have a valid PCINT for this pin
  if (digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin)) {
    #if GCC_VERSION > 40800
    // Timings counted from gcc 4.8.2 output. This works up to 115200 on
    // 16Mhz and 57600 on 8Mhz.
    //
    // When the start bit occurs, there are 3 or 4 cycles before the
    // interrupt flag is set, 4 cycles before the PC is set to the right
    // interrupt vector address and the old PC is pushed on the stack,
    // and then 75 cycles of instructions (including the RJMP in the
    // ISR vector table) until the first delay. After the delay, there
    // are 17 more cycles until the pin value is read (excluding the
    // delay in the loop).
    // We want to have a total delay of 1.5 bit time. Inside the loop,
    // we already wait for 1 bit time - 23 cycles, so here we wait for
    // 0.5 bit time - (71 + 18 - 22) cycles.
    _rx_delay_centering = subtract_cap(bit_delay / 2, (4 + 4 + 75 + 17 - 23) / 4);

    // There are 23 cycles in each loop iteration (excluding the delay)
    _rx_delay_intrabit = subtract_cap(bit_delay, 23 / 4);

    // There are 37 cycles from the last bit read to the start of
    // stopbit delay and 11 cycles from the delay until the interrupt
    // mask is enabled again (which _must_ happen during the stopbit).
    // This delay aims at 3/4 of a bit time, meaning the end of the
    // delay will be at 1/4th of the stopbit. This allows some extra
    // time for ISR cleanup, which makes 115200 baud at 16Mhz work more
    // reliably
    _rx_delay_stopbit = subtract_cap(bit_delay * 3 / 4, (37 + 11) / 4);
    #else // Timings counted from gcc 4.3.2 output
    // Note that this code is a _lot_ slower, mostly due to bad register
    // allocation choices of gcc. This works up to 57600 on 16Mhz and
    // 38400 on 8Mhz.
    _rx_delay_centering = subtract_cap(bit_delay / 2, (4 + 4 + 97 + 29 - 11) / 4);
    _rx_delay_intrabit = subtract_cap(bit_delay, 11 / 4);
    _rx_delay_stopbit = subtract_cap(bit_delay * 3 / 4, (44 + 17) / 4);
    #endif


    // Enable the PCINT for the entire port here, but never disable it
    // (others might also need it, so we disable the interrupt by using
    // the per-pin PCMSK register).
    *digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCICRbit(_receivePin));
    // Precalculate the pcint mask register and value, so setRxIntMask
    // can be used inside the ISR without costing too much time.
    _pcint_maskreg = digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin);
    _pcint_maskvalue = _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));

    tunedDelay(_tx_delay); // if we were low this establishes the end
  }

#if _DEBUG
  pinMode(_DEBUG_PIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(_DEBUG_PIN2, OUTPUT);
#endif

  listen();
}

void SoftwareSerial::setRxIntMsk(bool enable)
{
    if (enable)
      *_pcint_maskreg |= _pcint_maskvalue;
    else
      *_pcint_maskreg &= ~_pcint_maskvalue;
}

void SoftwareSerial::end()
{
  stopListening();
}


// Read data from buffer
int SoftwareSerial::read()
{
  if (!isListening())
    return -1;

  // Empty buffer?
  if (_receive_buffer_head == _receive_buffer_tail)
    return -1;

  // Read from "head"
  uint8_t d = _receive_buffer[_receive_buffer_head]; // grab next byte
  _receive_buffer_head = (_receive_buffer_head + 1) % _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF;
  return d;
}

int SoftwareSerial::available()
{
  if (!isListening())
    return 0;

  return (_receive_buffer_tail + _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF - _receive_buffer_head) % _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF;
}

size_t SoftwareSerial::write(uint8_t b)
{
  if (_tx_delay == 0) {
    setWriteError();
    return 0;
  }

  // By declaring these as local variables, the compiler will put them
  // in registers _before_ disabling interrupts and entering the
  // critical timing sections below, which makes it a lot easier to
  // verify the cycle timings
  volatile uint8_t *reg = _transmitPortRegister;
  uint8_t reg_mask = _transmitBitMask;
  uint8_t inv_mask = ~_transmitBitMask;
  uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
  bool inv = _inverse_logic;
  uint16_t delay = _tx_delay;

  if (inv)
    b = ~b;

  cli();  // turn off interrupts for a clean txmit

  // Write the start bit
  if (inv)
    *reg |= reg_mask;
  else
    *reg &= inv_mask;

  tunedDelay(delay);

  // Write each of the 8 bits
  for (uint8_t i = 8; i > 0; --i)
  {
    if (b & 1) // choose bit
      *reg |= reg_mask; // send 1
    else
      *reg &= inv_mask; // send 0

    tunedDelay(delay);
    b >>= 1;
  }

  // restore pin to natural state
  if (inv)
    *reg &= inv_mask;
  else
    *reg |= reg_mask;

  SREG = oldSREG; // turn interrupts back on
  tunedDelay(_tx_delay);

  return 1;
}

void SoftwareSerial::flush()
{
  // There is no tx buffering, simply return
}

int SoftwareSerial::peek()
{
  if (!isListening())
    return -1;

  // Empty buffer?
  if (_receive_buffer_head == _receive_buffer_tail)
    return -1;

  // Read from "head"
  return _receive_buffer[_receive_buffer_head];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a scope to check levels on the TX of the BT module. Some HC-xx modules come with 3.3V levels which can make problems.

I would suggest using the same speed for the serial port and for the bt dongle. You have a glitch here, which may make problems:

```
while(BtDongle.available()) {
  unsigned char data = BtDongle.read();
  Serial.println(data, HEX);
}
```

Eventually, the Bluetooth module sends you data at a high bit rate. You get the first letter, then send it out to the PC at a lower bit rate. Sending it out to the PC takes as long time as the BT dongle sends four more characters.

Although there are serial buffers in the Arduino, this problem will easily cause a loss of data, as @Avamander has pointed out.

Based on your comment telling that you were able to get an endless mess from Putty, this can escalate to losing the sync on the RX from the BT module, and then further bits will start a new byte, giving you a total mess. However, OK must work, so you likely have also level problems.

Answer (score 0):

I once had problems comunicating a GPS serial cable with an arduino. 
Conecting the gps to the PC serial port COM1 everything was ok.
but the arduino was receiving strange characters.
The solution was seting inverse_logic to true, the 3rd argument of SoftwareSerial.

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10,11,true);

maybe someone else can explain why some protocols are inverse